# Custom Filtering with Like Keyword-GridView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2007

I am using custom SPgridview with Filtering, and Sorting. In Filtering for the Query I have used has a condition as follows.

" AND SupplierActiveStatus LIKE '%{0}%'"

This has two values in DB. "Active" or "Inactive". This filter applies perfectly when you filter by Inactive. Due to "like" condition for the Active users it shows both types of uses without Filtering.

Please help me to find the correct filter expression to equal two strings.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get rid of the `LIKE` and just say:

`AND SupplierActiveStatus = '{0}'`

Since you have only two statuses, there's no reason to match on a wildcard with `LIKE`

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Garrison. You are correct. What I missed was when I set the Equality like a "Like" statement  '%{0}%' I had this percentage marks. Thanks for showing me the correct way.